# What is open expression of a vector's magnitude?

Tags: vectors

I'm 1st grade Physics student and my school started this week at 16.09.2019. I have seen 4.5 hours of lesson about vectors this week. We have seen such thing called *Products of Vectors*. My teacher told to class about *Properties of Scalar Product* with 6 items.

*Properties of Scalar Product*

1. $\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}=\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}$
2. $\vec{A}\cdot(\vec{B}+\vec{C})=\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}+\vec{A}\cdot\vec{C}$
3. $\vec{A}\cdot\vec{A}=AA\cos(\hat{\vec{A}, \vec{A}})=A^2\Rightarrow A=\sqrt{AA}$
4. $\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}\lt0\Rightarrow \epsilon\gt\frac{\pi}{2}$
5. $\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}=0\Rightarrow AB\cos{\theta}, \theta=(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi), (\frac{3\pi}{4}+2k\pi)$

$\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ are perpendicular or one of $\vec{A}$ or $\vec{B}$ is $0$.
6. $\vec{A}\cdot\vec{X}=k, k\in\Re\Rightarrow$ What is $\vec{X}$? 
This question doesn't have only one right answer. There are many $\vec{X}$ vectors that ensure $\vec{A}\cdot\vec{X}=k$ equation.

**

My first question is about 3rd item. Is the item correct?

My second question is about 4th question. Is $\theta\gt\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{\pi}{2}\lt\theta\lt\pi$ true?

And lastly we have seen such concept called *Open Expression of A Vector's Magnitude*.

$\vec{A}\cdot\vec{A}=(A_x\cdot\hat{x}+A_y\cdot\hat{y}+A_z\cdot\hat{z})\cdot(A_x\cdot\hat{x}+A_y\cdot\hat{y}+A_z\cdot\hat{z})$

$\vec{A}\cdot\vec{A}=A_x^2+A_y^2+A_z^2$

$\vec{A}\cdot\vec{A}=A^2$

$A=\left|\vec{A}\right|=\sqrt{A_x^2+A_y^2+A_z^2}$

Is the derivation and additional information correct? And also, what does *Open Expression of A Vector's Magnitude* mean?

Thanks!

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this maths question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 3rd item do you mean $\vec A \cdot \vec A = A^2$?  If so, yes that is correct. The dot product of 2 vectors is a scaler.  The 4th equation is correct also but note that $\theta$ varies by $0 \rightarrow \pi$.  I've never seen the term "open expression" used but from the equations above I think it means the obvious expressions. All the expressions look fine but #5. Again $0 \rightarrow \pi$.

Comment: Yeah, I mean that $\vec{A}\cdot\vec{A}=\left|\vec{A}\right|^2$ at 3rd item. I just translated what does mean the term "açık ifade" on the title of subject in Turkish. It showed me up "open expression" but, as I check it once more with "obvious expression" it shows same as "açık ifade". Your definition must be correct.  Thank you for validating the properties. I can not write things that my teacher wrote on the black board while I listening to him at the same time. So that, I can miss something and I can't be sure that I wrote correctly. Thank you again, have a good day!